# RDLC Report TextBox Properties for Decimal Display

Tags: report, rdlc, microsoft-dynamics

I was wondering if it was possible to do this type of display in RDLC report ? The decimal numbers after the colon display in the sample image below ? Is there any sort of properties for that ? Thanks

[image: Decimal Sample]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to Options:

1. Have two fields in your dataset, one is the 999 part and the other is the ,99 bit. Use two placeholders in the textbox and format the second one to superscript
2. Create the number as html (text) in your NAV code like this: `999,<sup>99</sup>` and tick "HTML - Interpret html tags as styles" in Textbox Properties -> General - Markup type. 
   Example : **999,<sup>99</sup>**

Cheers!